# Can an extending component find by aura:id in its base component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inheritance

I have a base (abstract) component:

```
<aura:component abstract="true" extensible="true">
    <aura:attribute name="instanceId" type="Object"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.onInit }"/>
    {! v.body }
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
</aura:component>
```

and this works fine in its controller:

```
onInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("workspace").getEnclosingTabId().then(
        function(id) {
            component.set("v.instanceId", id);
        }
    );
}
```

But when a component that extends this base component calls a helper method in the base supplying it's component reference, the `component.find("workspace")` fails (for my components - may be an error on my part).

Is this expected behavior i.e. an extending component can only find its own contained components by `aura:id` and not the base component's contained components?

Comment: @MarkPond Thanks. Think it is the same; will just leave it for a little while in case anyone has anything to add and then I'll click the "That solved my problem!" button.

Comment: Yeah it appears `getSuper()` will get the base component reference for your other helper functions to then use.